# Can someone evaluate the time complexity of this function

Tags: algorithm, time, complexity-theory

```
function    (n)
input : an  integer n
r ← 0
for i = 1 to n  //runs n times
    for j = i   + 1 to n     // runs n^2 times
           for k = i + j − 1 to n   //runs n^3 times
                r ← r + 1
return r
```

My answer was O(n^3), but when I tried finding it using sigma notation it always ends up being O(n^2).

Original question:

What     value   is  returned    by  the     following   algorithm?  What    is  its     basic   operation?  How
many     times   is  the     basic   operation   executed?   Give    the worst-case  running     time    of  the
algorithm   using   Big Oh  notation.

Answer (score 1):

**tldr:** The algorithm is in `O(n^3)`.

---

### Why?

Count how often `r <- r + 1` is executed.

If it helps, implement it in some language and execute it to get a better feeling for it. For example in Java:

```
int n = 10;

int r = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
        for (int k = i + j - 1; k <= n; k++) {
            r++;
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Introduction

The outer loop generates `n` iterations, correct. The second loop will then generate `n - 1, n - 2, n - 3, n - 4, ...` generations.

The innermost loop however depends on `i`, `j` and `n`.

Example, fix `i = 1` and let `j` run from `n - 1` to `1`. You will get `k` `1 + (n - 1)` to `n` which are no runs at all. Then `1 + (n - 2)` to `n` which are `2` runs, up to `n` runs.

So with `i = 1` you will get `k = 2, 3, 4, ..., n`. Then `i = 2` and you get `k = 4, ..., n + (n + 1)`. This repeats and sums up until `i = n` yields only `k = (n+(n-2))`, in total:

```
i = 1 -> k = 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ..., n
i = 2 -> k =       4, 5, 6, ..., n, (n+1)
i = 3 -> k =             6, ..., n, (n+1), (n+2)
  .
  .
  .
i = n -> k =                  (n+(n-2))
```

For the example with `n = 10` this is:

```
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 
      4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
            6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
                  8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13
                        10, 11, 12, 13, 14
                                12, 13, 14, 15
                                        14, 15, 16
                                                16, 17
                                                        18
```

for `k`.

---

### Values for `k`

Now note that the loop only executes until `k <= n`. So you can discard all values for `k` higher than `n` and count the iterations for the remaining values.

```
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10| 
      4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10|, 11
            6, 7, 8, 9, 10|, 11, 12
                  8, 9, 10|, 11, 12, 13
                        10|, 11, 12, 13, 14
                          |     12, 13, 14, 15
                          |             14, 15, 16
                          |                    16, 17
                          |                           18
```

---

### Total runs

So each of those is a value for `k` and it will generate `(n + 1) - k` many runs. So do that and you get:

```
9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
      7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
            5, 4, 3, 2, 1
                  3, 2, 1
                        1
```

Sum those up and you finally get the amount of total runs:

```
9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1
      + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1
              + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1
                      + 3 + 2 + 1
                              + 1
```

Which yields `r = 95`.

---

### Formula and proof

The exact formula for that is:

```
sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} ceil((n - i) / 2) * i
```

If you drop the `ceil` (it wont affect the complexity) you can simplify this to

```
n^3 / 12 - n / 12
```

And now you can easily see and prove that this is in `O(n^3)`.